# How to change the display resolution in Ubuntu 21.04 (with Wayland)

Tags: display, display-resolution, wayland, 21.04

Today I updated my Ubuntu to 21.04. Since then I cannot choose the correct resolution for my display. Here is the old version I used for years on Ubuntu, which doesn't work anymore:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 2304 x 800, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 260mm x 160mm
   1280x800      59.81*+
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND1 connected 1024x768+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      59.92*+
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
$ cvt 1680 1050  
# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
$ sudo xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 "1680x1050_60.00"
$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --mode "1680x1050_60.00"                                                    
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x500
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

I also tried adding the video mode as a kernel parameter with [these](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-wayland-xorg/) instructions. But that didn't work either. Maybe it didn't work because of that:

> You can’t set custom resolution higher than the maximum one in Display settings. In my case (see the picture above), X resolution must be less than 1920, and Y resolution have to less than 1080

The maximum resolution in my settings dialogue is 1024x768, but that is not the correct solution.

Does anyone got an idea what to do next? Thank you!

**Edit:**

One solution is to choose the old X11 window manager at login instead of wayland. Then the old method is still working. But is there a way doing it with wayland?

Comment: I have the same problem :-(